# mongo date issues

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So I need help in trying to understand the following?

In mongo shell, I did this:

```
 > var start = new Date(2011,2,2,8,0,0)
```

and then start gives me:

```
  > start
  ISODate("2011-03-02T16:00:00Z")
```

What i was expecting to parse was a date variable been created which is of the following type

2nd feb 2011 8 am 
in format( yyyy-mm-dd) python format.

I cant understand what happend?

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really think it is a Javascript Date issue, where your month is actually one number less than the actual month

e.g. February is 1, as noted in the w3c

> Note: January is 0, February is 1, and so on.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp

And about the time, this is a time-zone issue try using

```
start.setUTCHours(8)
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

You could get the string by doing

```
start.toUTCString();
```